# Units in a ring not in ideal generated by $\langle 3 \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Sorry for the clumsy title, it was hard to put something so specific into a short title.

We have a ring $R=\{a+b\sqrt{7} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. Additionally we know that $3=-(2-\sqrt{7})(2+\sqrt{7})$, with $2-\sqrt{7} \in R$ and $2+\sqrt{7} \in R$. We know additionally that these are not units of R.

The above is from some previous questions on an exam paper. The current question with some explanatory notes that has been confusing us is:

Show that the ideal $I = \langle 3 \rangle$ generated by 3 in $R$ is not a maximal ideal.

The first part of the explanatory note says:

"Since we know that $2-\sqrt{7}$ and $2+\sqrt{7}$ are **not** units in $R$, then neither $2+\sqrt{7}$ nor $2-\sqrt{7}$ are in $\langle 3 \rangle$"

Why is this? We don't see why this must be the case. We don't see the connection between being a unit and being in the generated ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: It is pretty clear that $(3)\subseteq (2+\sqrt{7})$ because of your relation. If the converse inclusion holds then $(3)= (2+\sqrt{7})$ and that would mean that $3=u(2+\sqrt{7})$ for some unit $u$. That would imply that $(2-\sqrt{7})$ is a unit.

Comment: Thanks A.Rod. Would you like to make this comment an answer so that I can give you credit?